# Is it true that $\int_1^ba^{\log_b x}dx> \log_eb$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is it true that

$\int_1^ba^{\log_b x}dx> \log_eb$

$\forall a,b>0\ and\ b\not = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$u:=\log_bx\implies du=\frac{dx}{x\log b}\implies dx=b^u\log b\;du$$

$$\int\limits_1^b a^{\log_bx}dx=\log b\int\limits_0^1 (ab)^udu=\left.\frac{\log b}{\log ab}(ab)^u\right|_0^1\ge \log b\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$a^{\log_b x}= x^{\log_b a}$$

After using this formula you get an easy to calculate integral.